# Django complex query and display

Tags: python, django

I have a `Project` model, with some instances in it. I have another model `Progress` to keep the progress of each project every month. Here is the model:

```
class Progress(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    month = models.DateField() # just use the first day to refer the month, not the key point
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

However, projects may not start at the same time. So in our database, we may have rows like:

```
id | project_id | month      | value
1  | 1          | 2014-01-01 | 10
2  | 1          | 2014-02-01 | 20
3  | 2          | 2014-02-01 | 15
4  | 1          | 2014-03-01 | 30
5  | 2          | 2014-03-01 | 30
```

I want to have an output like this:

```
         | 14-01 | 14-02 | 14-03
project1 | 10    | 20    | 30
project2 | /     | 15    | 30
```

For empty cells, both slash or zero will be ok. I don't know how to generate 6 cells with 5 rows of data. Should I implement this in template or in view?

---

I tried in template, but since django template doesn't support break, continue of loop, it may not be an easy job. Thus I prefer to use view to generate the ready-to-render data.

Any ideas or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean about the output you want. You want to write some SQL query that will return output like that at the db-level or what? I think also your model structure could be better.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist In my case, the queryset `Progress.objects.all()` will return all data I need, with no redundancy. So the key points is how to output the query. Passing the raw data to Template or changing the structure in View? Also, the optimization of model is welcome.